# C++/winRT xaml Keyboard Event handler

Tags: c++-winrt

The following, when compiled, produces a "1 unresolved externals..."
My question is - what are the proper parameters?

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;

xaml
KeyDown="Keyboard_keyDown"

 .h
 void Keyboard_keyDown(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, 
   Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs e);

 .cpp
 void SettingsPage::Keyboard_keyDown(IInspectable const& sender,
Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs e) {...}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="BlankAppKeypaderror.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BlankAppKeypaderror"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"

KeyDown="Keyboard_keyDown"

>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click Me</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

> MainPage.h
>
> ## pragma once
>
> ## include "MainPage.g.h"
>
> namespace winrt::DemoProblemApp::implementation {
>       struct MainPage : MainPageT
>       {
>           MainPage();
>
> ```
>     int32_t MyProperty();
>     void MyProperty(int32_t value);
>     void Keyboard_keyDown(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs e);
>     void ClickHandler(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& args);
> }; }
> ```
>
> namespace winrt::DemoProblemApp::factory_implementation {
>       struct MainPage : MainPageT
>       {
>       }; }

MainPage.cpp

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::DemoProblemApp::implementation {
    MainPage::MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int32_t MainPage::MyProperty() {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void MainPage::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */) {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs   const&) {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));
    }

    void MainPage::Keyboard_keyDown(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable     const& sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs e) {

    }


}
```

I changed the handlers (,h & ,cpp) to the following and problem exists:
        void Keyboard_KeyDown(Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&     sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyRoutedEventArgs const& e);

2018-1207 - included this in the .h file

## include

Comment: Please show a [mcve] as well as the **full** error message.

Comment: To recreate the problem create a C++/winRT - blank app . In MainPage.xaml add the above code. The same with MainPage.h & MainPage.cpp.

Comment: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::KeyEventHandler::KeyEventHandler<class <lambda_749e65c22c238cb0f46e09967a2baf1e> >(class <lambda_749e65c22c238cb0f46e09967a2baf1e>)" (??$?0V<lambda_749e65c22c238cb0f46e09967a2baf1e>@@@KeyEventHandler@Input@Xaml@UI@Windows@winrt@@QAE@V<lambda_749e65c22c238cb0f46e09967a2baf1e>@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall winrt::DemoProblemApp::implementation::MainPageT<struct winrt::DemoProblemApp::implementation::MainPage>::Connect(int,struct win

Comment: `{...}` isn't valid code. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: The following is an excerpt from a C++/winRT BlankApp

Comment: Perhaps compare it to the `ClickHandler` next to it, which declares the final parameter as `const&`.

Answer (score 1):

This was missing in the .H file

```
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.h>
```